# firebase function on db trigger throws Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

my firebase function based on realtime database trigger looks like below

```
exports.on_user_created = functions.database.ref("/users/{id}")
    .onCreate((change, context) => {
        console.log("start of on_user_created ")   
        const user = change.val();
        console.log("New user:::" + JSON.stringify(user))

        const uid = user._uid
        const referralCode = user._referralCode

        console.log("creating referral node for uid:" + uid + " with code:" + referralCode)

        if(referralCode === undefined){
            console.error("No referral code created for the user while sign up. Referral node cannot be created.")    
            return true
        }


        var db = admin.database();
        var ref = db.ref('referrals')

        ref.child(referralCode).set({"uid": uid}).then(
            (resp) => {
                        console.log("referral node created")
                        return true
                      }
          ).catch(
            (err) => {
                      console.error("unable to create referral node on user create:" + err)    
                      return true  
            }
        )    
})
```

it on run throws

```
 5:47:02.035 AM on_user_created  Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value
```

I am failing to understand why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Adapted following Doug's comment below: "If you have no async work to be done, it's typical to return `null`"*

This is because you don't return the Promise returned by the [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#set) asynchronous operation.

You should do something like:

```
exports.on_user_created = functions.database.ref("/users/{id}")
    .onCreate((change, context) => {
        console.log("start of on_user_created ")   
        const user = change.val();
        console.log("New user:::" + JSON.stringify(user))

        const uid = user._uid
        const referralCode = user._referralCode

        console.log("creating referral node for uid:" + uid + " with code:" + referralCode)

        if(referralCode === undefined){
            console.error("No referral code created for the user while sign up. Referral node cannot be created.")    
            return null  // <-- See Doug's comment below.
        }

        var db = admin.database();
        var ref = db.ref('referrals')

        return ref.child(referralCode).set({"uid": uid}).then( // <-- !! Here we return
            (resp) => {
                        console.log("referral node created")
                        return null
                      }
          ).catch(
            (err) => {
                      console.error("unable to create referral node on user create:" + err)    
                      return null  
            }
        )    
})
```

Note that you could streamline your code as follows if you don't need the `console.log()`s, e.g. for production.

```
exports.on_user_created = functions.database.ref("/users/{id}")
    .onCreate((change, context) => { 
        const user = change.val();
        const uid = user._uid
        const referralCode = user._referralCode

        if (referralCode === undefined) {
            return null;
        } else {
            var db = admin.database();
            var ref = db.ref('referrals')

            return ref.child(referralCode).set({"uid": uid});
        }

});
```

For more detail on the importance of returning the promises in a Cloud Function, I would suggest you watch the official video series and in particular the ones titled "Learn JavaScript Promises": https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

Comment: well i need the console.log else it's hard to track what kind of data caused error even in production

Comment: Sure! It is not a problem to use them, it was just an extra consideration worth to note.

Comment: so another question related to this. you mentioned about return true or false. sure make sense. but as it's a db trigger where does it really return that value? it's not a regular http function which i can make call and subscribe to it. so how do i make use of that useful return condition?

Comment: Not 100% sure to understand your question: if you ask what is the goal of returning true or false, it is a way to indicate to the platform executing the Cloud Function that the Function is finished (in this case it is finished with a result that is not the intended one -referralCode === undefined or other error-, but it is finished). Some return a 0 or a 1 instead of false or true.

Comment: sorry to confuse u. let me write again: so by reading the code it makes sense when i m returning a true or false. understood the benefit of that.  now the question is: can i programmatically make use of this returned value  somewhere? when i say return true or return false. i dont really get where it is actually returning this value. it's a firebase function so as such there is no programmer controlled invoking piece to this trigger when i can do more based on the returned value. make sense?

Comment: Ok, I got it :-) It returns to the Google Cloud Platform instance that runs your Cloud Function, indicating that the Function is finished and that the platform can immediately release the resources used for it instead of waiting to reach the time out.

Comment: correct so basically returning true or false is just semantic for me. as i cannot do anything on the returned value. right?

Comment: As far as I know, yes.

Comment: If you have no async work to be done, it's typical to return `null` instead of a boolean.  The function is supposed to return a promise, but a boolean is not a promise.  null is a valid value for a promise, and it indicates you have no async work.

Comment: Doug interesting to know that and that sounds more appropriate to use rather true fasle