# Firebase messaging app/network-timeout from firebase functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

my push notification code from the firebase function looks like below:

```
 //fetch push tokens of all admins as well to send push notification
        var tokens = []

        if(pushToken !== undefined && pushToken !== '')
            tokens.push(pushToken)

        tokens = tokens.concat(adminPushTokens)


        //push tokens need to be of customer as well as all the admins in the system. fetch admin push tokens
        admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, pushPayload).then(
            (resp) => console.log("push notification sent")
        ).catch(
            (err) => console.error("Error sending push notification:" + JSON.stringify(err))
        )
```

And for 15-20% of the time it ends up in

```
 Error sending push notification:{"code":"app/network-timeout","message":"fcm.googleapis.com network timeout. Please try again."}
```

This is a big issue for us and not an acceptable performance. How can we make sure to improve the reliability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably the same problem than the one of your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53527015/firebase-function-on-db-trigger-throws-function-returned-undefined-expected-pro): you shall return the promise returned by the asynchronous [`sendToDevice()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging.Messaging#sendToDevice) method. If you don't return the promise, the Cloud Function will not wait for the asynchronous task to fully complete.

So you should do:

```
return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, pushPayload).then({});
```

Comment: i have put the code changes and your answer sounds good. i will mark it correct by tomorrow if this resolves the issue

Comment: Note that, in my answer, I made the assumption that it is a background triggered Cloud Function